# epoll_wait doesn't wake up until pressing on enter

Tags: c++, epoll

I'm new with epoll. 
My code is working fine. The epoll is storing my file-descriptor and wait until file-descriptor is "ready".
But, for some reason it will not wake up until I will press on Enter (even though data has already received to fd, and after enter I will immediately see all data that has been sent before).
After one enter it will work as expected (no enters needed and when fd is ready again it will wake up again).

Here is am essence of my code:

```c
    int nEventCountReady = 0;
    epoll_event event, events[EPOLL_MAX_EVENTS];
    int epoll_fd = epoll_create1(0);

    if(epoll_fd == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Failed to create EPoll" << std::endl;
        return ;
    }

    event.events = EPOLLIN;
    event.data.fd = myfd;

    if(epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 0, &event))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to add file descriptor to epoll\n");
        close(epoll_fd);
        return ;
    }

    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << "Waiting for messages" << std::endl;
        nEventCountReady = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events, EPOLL_MAX_EVENTS, 30000); << Stuck until Enter will be pressed (at first while loop)
        for(int i=0; i<nEventCountReady; i++)
        {
            msgrcv(events[i].data.fd, oIpCMessageContent, sizeof(SIPCMessageContent), 1, 0);
            std::cout << oIpCMessageContent.buff << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `event.data.fd = myfd;` - what is `myfd`? How was it opened?

Comment: just a normal file-descriptor.. 
To be more specific, fd is a file descriptor of msgget.

Comment: You should make a [mcve].

Comment: I do not think `msgget` returns a file descriptor. From the look I *guess* `myfd` is equal to `STDIN_FILENO` and you are really polling `stdin`. Which kind-of maybe explains it - you poll STDIN, block until you type something and type enter because it's line buffered, then you do not read anything from stsdin, so `epoll_wait` returns immiedately. `To be more specific` - please be more specific.

Comment: @KamilCuk the result of msgget function is not equal to STDIN_FILENO, but I just read about msgget and you right about this function that it does not return a file descriptor, it returns "System V message queue identifier" which I thought is a file descriptor.

Comment: I just read that too and it explains the `EBADF` you get if you try to use it as a file descriptor.

Comment: `the result of msgget function is not equal to STDIN_FILENO` Are you sure? What value does it result then?

Comment: @KamilCuk the fd value is 1015829. Which is the "System V message queue identifier"

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm starting to understand that if I want to use epoll I can't use msgget, because it doesn't return a file-descriptor at all.. 1 option is to find an alternative to msgget that use file-descriptor. second option is to find a way to epoll_wait that works on msgget (or to be more specific, "System V message queue identifier")

Comment: An old technique that may be of use is the "_self-pipe trick_". In short, you create a pair of file descriptors (using `pipe`) and have a dedicated process/thread that waits on the non-file descriptor resource. When something happens, it'll signal that using its end of the pipe.

Comment: `I'm starting to understand that if I want to use epoll I can't use msgget`  - offtopic to this question, use POSIX IPC, not the really old System V IPC. It seems strange to use the newest epoll with the oldest System V. | What is the value of `events[i].data.fd` ? How was it initialized? Please post an [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to kamilCuk, I noticed that msgget doesn't return a file descriptor as I thought. 
It returns a "System V message queue identifier".

And as freakish said before, System V message queues don't work with selectors like epoll.

Comment: I suggest that you accept freakish's answer since it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
if(epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 0, &event))
```

should probably be

```
if(epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, myfd, &event))
```

In the first line you tell epoll to monitor fd 0 which is typically the standard input. That's why it waits for it, e.g. for your Enter.

Note that your original code works only by coincidence. It just happens that when you Enter there is data in your `myfd` (and even if there's none `msgrcv` blocks). And once you pressed Enter it will wake up all the time since epoll knows that STDIN is ready but you didn't read from it.

Comment: I have tried this before, but when I'm doing this epoll_ctl always return -1.
So I though this way was not correct and I should put 0.
Anyway, it returns -1 and errno is 9 (which is 'EBADF'). As I said before, my fd generated by the function msgget).

Comment: Adding `0` makes it wait for events on `stdin`, so this is the correct answer.

Comment: @YaronIsraeli msgget does not return a file descriptor. AFAIK System V message queues don't work with selectors like epoll.